# I want to redirect my old domain all the page urls with new domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect my old domain urls with new domain with htaccess file.I have tried but it only works in root folder files when I access pages with Subdirectory from old domain it redirects to home page.
so anyone has proper solution?
**For e.g.**
My old url
**www.olddomain.com/dir1/page1.php**
Now when user goes to above link it will directly goes to
**www.newdomain.com/dir1/page1.php**

Comment: Can you provide the domains you're trying to redirect?

Answer (score 1):

All you should need to do however is include this in the .htaccess of your old domain:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For specific directories:

```
Redirect 301 /mydir http://www.new-domain.com
```

or if it is to go to another directory:

```
Redirect 301 /mydir http://www.new-domain.com/mydir
```

Comment: Currently both the domains are pointed to same host.but i need the old domain to redirect to new domain.Not working in subdirectory pages

Comment: See my edit for specific directories. Hope that helps.